# fvwm-menu-desktop hanging during menu creation and failing with python exception when using --get-menus

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 and have fvwm, I had the fvwm-menu-desktop that created the menus for me but lately it started behaving totally bad:

(I use the command
 `fvwm-menu-desktop --desktop gnome --type gtk --theme masalla  --title FvwmKde` to generate my menu
)

1. it generates twice the menu
2. it hangs half way (twice) just before creating the *Android Studio* menu item, (is that a hint?)
3. when I try to check the desktop menus available, it throws a python exception error:

```
$ fvwm-menu-desktop --get-menus desktop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fvwm-menu-desktop", line 821, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/fvwm-menu-desktop", line 388, in main
    parsemenus(menulist, desktop)
  File "/usr/bin/fvwm-menu-desktop", line 677, in parsemenus
    parsemenu(xdg.Menu.parse(menu), name, title)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 1137, in parse
    return XMLMenuBuilder(debug).parse(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 641, in parse
    menu = self.parse_menu(tree.getroot(), filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 659, in parse_menu
    self.parse_node(node, filename, menu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 668, in parse_node
    menu = self.parse_menu(child, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 659, in parse_menu
    self.parse_node(node, filename, menu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 668, in parse_node
    menu = self.parse_menu(child, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 659, in parse_menu
    self.parse_node(node, filename, menu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 691, in parse_node
    parent.Rules.append(self.parse_rule(child))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 768, in parse_rule
    return Rule(type, tree)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py", line 421, in __init__
    self.code = compile(self.expression, '<compiled-menu-rule>', 'eval')
ValueError: Name node can't be used with 'True' constant
```

I have
Ubuntu 20.04
fvwm 2.6.8 compiled on Jan 14 2019 at 19:59:25 with support for: ReadLine, RPlay, Stroke, XPM, SVG, Shape, XShm, SM, Bidi text, Xinerama, XRender, XCursor, XFT, NLS

```
 mau  ~  python --version
Python 2.7.18
 mau  ~  python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this a late answer, but I just ran into the same problem.

It is due to a change in Python 3.8.4 causing a problem in pyxdg. Here's the bug report:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/pyxdg/-/issues/20

And here's the patch to Menu.py:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/pyxdg/-/commit/9b913229ace838958e51a16cabc41905a2460f7b

I updated my /usr/lib/python3-dist-packages/xdg/Menu.py and the problem went away.